# How to add a spatial Cartesian coordinate system to a three-dimensional figure and color the corresponding plane?

Tags: graphics3d

The code for drawing three-dimensional graphics is:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c = {0, 0, 0};
d = {2, 0, 0};
b = {0, 2, 0};
a = b + d;
h = 4;
c1 = {0, 0, h};
d1 = d + c1
a1 = a + c1
b1 = b + c1
a2 = {1/4, 3/4} . {a1, a}
b2 = {1/2, 1/2} . {b1, b}
d2 = {1/2, 1/2} . {d1, d}
c2 = 3/4  c1
p = Block[{t = 1/4}, {1 - t, t} . {b1, b}]
labels = {Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[A1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a1, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[B1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b1, {-1, -2}], 
   Text[Style[C1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c1, {0, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d1, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[A2, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a2, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[B2, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b2, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[C2, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c2, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[D2, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d2, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[P, 12, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], p, {3, 0}]};
dashLines = {Dashed, 
   AbsoluteThickness[2], {Blue, Line[{{c2, p}}]}, {Red, 
    Line[{{c, d}, {c1, c}, {c, b}, {c2, d2}, {c2, b2}}]}, 
   Line[{{a2, c2}}]};
realLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{{a, d}, {a, b}, {a1, a}, {b, b1}, {a1, d1}, {a1, b1}, {c1, 
      d1}, {b1, c1}, {d, d1}, {a2, d2}, {a2, p}, {a2, b2}}]};
Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {2, 3.5, 1.28}]
```

1.I want to add a spatial Cartesian coordinate system to it. Using point C as the origin of the coordinate system, the line where CD is located is the x-axis, the line where CB is located is the y-axis, and the line where CC1 is located is the z-axis. The effect after establishment is shown in the following figure.

[image]

2.How to color the specified plane? For example, color plane A2C2D2 red, and color plane ABCD blue.

Update 1: based on cvgmt,thanks for your help

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c = {0, 0, 0};
d = {2, 0, 0};
b = {0, 2, 0};
a = b + d;
h = 4;
c1 = {0, 0, h};
d1 = d + c1
a1 = a + c1
b1 = b + c1
a2 = {1/4, 3/4} . {a1, a}
b2 = {1/2, 1/2} . {b1, b}
d2 = {1/2, 1/2} . {d1, d}
c2 = 3/4  c1
p = Block[{t = 1/4}, {1 - t, t} . {b1, b}]
labels = {Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[A1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a1, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[B1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b1, {-1, -2}], 
   Text[Style[C1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c1, {0, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d1, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[A2, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a2, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[B2, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b2, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[C2, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c2, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[D2, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d2, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[P, 12, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], p, {3, 0}]};
dashLines = {Dashed, 
   AbsoluteThickness[2], {Blue, Line[{{c2, p}}]}, {Red, 
    Line[{{c, d}, {c1, c}, {c, b}, {c2, d2}, {c2, b2}}]}, 
   Line[{{a2, c2}}]};
realLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{{a, d}, {a, b}, {a1, a}, {b, b1}, {a1, d1}, {a1, b1}, {c1, 
      d1}, {b1, c1}, {d, d1}, {a2, d2}, {a2, p}, {a2, b2}}]};
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {2, 3.5, 1.28}], 
 RegionPlot3D[Polygon[{a2, c2, d2}], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 + #3 &}, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Pink], 
 RegionPlot3D[Polygon[{a, b, c, d}], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 + #3 &}, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Cyan], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{c1, c1 + {0, 0, 1}}, {d, d + {1, 0, 0}}, {b, 
      b + {0, 1, 0}}}], 
   Text[Style["z", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    c1 + {0, 0, 1}, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style["y", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    b + {0, 1, 0}, {-2, -1}], 
   Text[Style["x", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    d + {1, 0, 0}, {2, -1}]}]]
```

Comment: Use `Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> c` in `Graphics3D`.

Comment: The arrows on the three coordinate axes do not have

Comment: Search [arrow axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=arrows+axes) – plenty of questions and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {2, 3.5, 1.28}], 
 RegionPlot3D[Polygon[{a2, c2, d2}], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 + #3 &}, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Pink], 
 RegionPlot3D[Polygon[{a, b, c, d}], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 + #3 &}, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Cyan], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{c1, c1 + {0, 0, 1}}, {d, d + {1, 0, 0}}, {b, 
      b + {0, 1, 0}}}], 
   Text[Style["z", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    c1 + {0, 0, 1}, {-1, -1}]}]]
```

[image]